# Sacar Informacion de un String

Tags: c#

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]hola tengo una cadena de caracteres en la cual quisiera sacar cierta información
Signal level=-9 dBm esta información deseo sacar de esa cadena pero no se como hacer en c#
gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

muchas gracias por haberme ayudado funciona bien me escanea todas las redes y me señala la mas potente ahora quisiera sus opiniones sobre ese código y como podría optimizarlo

Comment: Para la proxima vez, pon un ejemplo de tu codigo (o por lo menos lo que intentaste) y tambien un ejemplo de tu cadena.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado un string cualquiera, puedes ubicar un substring del mismo usando la funcion `string.indexof`. Con eso, obtenes la posicion de un pedazo del string. Entonces podriamos tratar de ubicar "Signal level=", dentro de tu string. Una vez ubicado eso, tambien podemos buscar "dBm", para saber cuantos caracteres hay en el medio. Y con eso, obtener el valor que estas buscando.

```
string cadena = @"hola tengo una cadena de caracteres en la cual quisiera sacar cierta información Signal level=-9 dBm esta información deseo sacar de esa cadena pero no se como hacer en c# gracias";
int pos = cadena.IndexOf("Signal level") + ("Signal level=").Length;
int lastpos = cadena.IndexOf("dBm")+3;
string valor = cadena.Substring(pos, lastpos - pos);
Console.WriteLine(valor);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Puedes probar el codigo anterior en una aplicacion de consola, y veras que imprime el valor que estas buscando. De ser necesario, puedes ajustar los valores de inicio y fin (por si hay espacios o cosas asi).

En el ejemplo, use la cadena de tu pregunta, `("Signal level=").Length;` Esta instruccion por ejemplo te devuelve el largo de esa cadena, ya que indexof, devuelve el inicio de la cadena que estas buscando.

Comment: ("Signal level=").Length  o 12 una constantre

Comment: exacto. lo que sea mas comodo

Comment: un pregunta que parasia si tengo 2 Signal level= en il mismo string solo me leeria el primero

Comment: la funcion indexof puede recibir como parametro tambien desde que posicion buscar. Una vez que encuentres el primero, si le pasas como inicio lastpos, va a empezar a buscar desde ahi y va a encontrar el proximo

Comment: lo que se me ocure es meter todo en string en un array  y seraralo con split y despues recorer ese aray     algo asi                                                                                                          
          foreach (var item in tokens)
            {
                if (item.Contains("ESSID"))
                {
                    listBox3.Items.Add(item);
                }
                if (item.Contains("Quality"))
                {
                  listBox4.Items.Add(item);
               }  }

Comment: y para que? si con lo que te pase resolves todo el string de una?

Comment: mira la foto que puse ahi  saltrian 3 resultados diferentes como lo haria para sacacarlos individualmente los 3 los que estan marcados con azul y con rojo y tambien te tria qe relacionarlos carlosprueva1 con 31 carlosprueva2 con 32 y carlosprueva3 con 33

Comment: Eso es otro ejercicio completamente diferente, no es lo que planteaste al principio. Y con lo que te pase, lo podrias hacer igual. Ahora, deja de poner imagenes en las preguntas, pon el codigo que llevas. No actualices tu pregunta, si no tengo que ir cambiando la respuesta a cada rato. Intenta con lo que te dije, y si encuentras otro error abre otra pregunta con ese problema en particular. Las coas las podes ir sacando y guardando donde quieras, no tengo info de que queres hacer con cada dato que sacas. Asi como estas trabajando, es dificil ayudarte porque no sos claro. @carlos1016

Comment: Dale pero muchas gracias la logré a ser lo funcionar  gracias a todos

Comment: Recuerda como funciona el sitio (haz el [tour] si no lo hiciste). Marca la respuesta que sea la correcta y te haya servido como aceptada. Tambien, si tienes mas problemas y se referencian a esta pregunta, no dudes en poner un link a la misma en tu nueva pregunta. @carlos1016

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar la función Split para separar toda esa línea que es una variable de tipo `String` en un *array* de sub-strings. Eso sí, sería más fácil si agregaras a tu *array total* (Que en este caso es `Quality=87/94 Signal level=9dBm Noise level=103dBm`) una separación. Por ejemplo, con comas; dicho de otra manera, que estuviera de la siguiente forma:

```
Quality=87/94, Signal level=9dBm, Noise level=103dBm
```

Así separas ese string en substrings, y cada substring lo almacena en un array. Al final pondrás en el cuadro de texto la posición del array que tiene el sub-string que tenga `Signal level=9dBm`.

```
string charCommaString = "Quality=87/94, Signal level=9dBm, Noise level=103dBm";
char[] commaSeparator = new char[] { ',' };
string[] result;
result = charCommaString.Split(commaSeparator, StringSplitOptions.None);
Console.WriteLine(result[1]);
```

Mira que mi string `charCommaString` contiene toda la línea que quieres extraer sólo una parte. Solo añadí 3 comas.

En la cuarta línea de código lo que hago es usar el método `Split()`, que se encarga de  separ el texto de la variable `String charCommaString` en sub-strings cada vez que encuentre un separador. En este caso, el separador es una coma ",".

Espero te sirva mi respuesta.

Comment: si pero no puedo agregar las comas esa linea me la devuelve  un server  no la puedo modificar

Comment: Sólo necesitarás extraer esa información en esa línea?

Comment: si pero ese 9dBm puede variar  puede ser menos o mas